# Does anyone know if NSISdl will be updated to support HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https, nsis, sha1

I originally asked a question about NSISDl because I thought there was a bug or issue with my use of it. Through this ticket, I found out it does not support HTTPS at all, and thus it became an entirely different matter. (edit)

Comment: Really? An installer script with it's own language isn't programming?

Comment: NSIS is fine as long as you ask a specific programming question

Comment: This is about the use of an extension to the language itself, I would argue.

Comment: I don't make the rules. General software questions can be asked on Super User, though I think this should have been a bug report ir feature request on SourceForge

Comment: Hindsight is 20/20 and I still think it is on-topic.

Comment: I discovered that using HTTP it works in Windows 2012 (and prob Win7), but fails in Windows 10. I am just going to develop my own little 'downloadfile' app to facilitate our needs going forward. I appreciate you guys answering my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSISdl only supports plain HTTP. Use the [INetC plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in) instead, it uses WinInet and should work anywhere Internet Explorer works...

Comment: I've been using HTTPS for years with it, so it at least unofficially supports HTTPS ;). Thanks!

Comment: NSISdl contains no crypto code IIRC, it is just a basic HTTP client on top of a TCP socket. It was written back when Win95 was relevant and had nothing except basic sockets...

Comment: I know that to be false for a fact since I use it actively. I may have gotten an updated build at some point, but HTTPS (/w SHA1) definitely works, no question at all.

Comment: Then you must be using some unofficial plug-in build or a server that downgrades to HTTP.

Comment: ...and don't hold your breath for upgrades. If anything, we would drop NSISdl and clone INetC.

Comment: JNL_HTTPGet::do_parse_url doesn't appear to look at the protocol scheme at all; it simply looks for ://. Maybe it should so users aren't surprised?

Comment: @EricLaw: Probably, I think it mostly cares about username/password and maybe a custom port in the URL when parsing at that point. I'm guessing it does not look at the scheme because it never supported anything except plain HTTP. The JNL network library probably came from WinAmp and written to support the things they needed back then.

Comment: As I posted above, to conclude "I discovered that using HTTP it works in Windows 2012 (and prob Win7), but fails in Windows 10. I am just going to develop my own little 'downloadfile' app to facilitate our needs going forward. I appreciate you guys answering my question!"